# Jira Kanban board does not show cards, although there seem to be issues

Tags: jira, kanban

From one day to another, changing the issue filter slightly, my Kanban board's board configuration in JIRA went empty. I use the following JQL as a filter within the board configuration:

```
project = "My amazing project" and fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() 
    ORDER BY priority DESC
```

The above filter does not work. What is working, though, is

```
project = "My amazing project" and fixVersion = "v1337" 
    ORDER BY priority DESC
```

Interestingly, the first query works in JIRA's issue explorer and gives me back the 11 results I expect. As you see in the screenshot below, I have no quick filters enabled. Neither do I have any sub-filter added, nor am I hiding any older issues. **Where did all the cards go?**

[image: Screenshot of empty Kanban Board]

I am using Atlassian Jira Project Management Software (v8.2.3#802003-sha1:5986657), and I am not an administrator of that installation, only of the project.

[image: Screenshot of board configuration]

#### Further reading

- [community.atlassian.com: Kanban board is empty](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Kanban-board-is-empty/qaq-p/792836)

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the Kanban board configuration? Also, have you tried it with a different web browser? In the Kanban columns it shows that 11 cards should be in the first two columns...weird.

Comment: @ChrisGraf I included a screenshot of the configuration. It is indeed weird. As I said, the filter query works in the issue explorer. And: It looks the same in Chrome and in Firefox (both at newest version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [dedicated problem page provided by Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILEKB/Can%27t+See+Issues+in+Kanban+Board):

> #### Symptoms
>
> The issues are not visible in Kanban board, but when you are in board configurations >> columns you can see number of issues.
>
> #### Cause
>
> As Kanban board deals with version of the issues, the field named Fix **Version/s** should not be hidden
>   This is because the default Kanban board sub-filter(Board Configure >> General) has been set to
>
> ```
> fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() OR fixVersion is EMPTY
> ```

The page also describes a rather complicated workaround. My workaround was much simpler:

1. Change the JQL query to `project = "My amazing project"` only.
2. Create a subfilter `fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() ORDER BY priority DESC`.

I do not understand why it has to be this way, but it does the job.